# Global sections of the Hom sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $F$ and $G$ be $O_X$-modules, and consider the Hom sheaf $\mathcal{H}om_{O_X}(F,G)$. What are the global sections of this sheaf?

I know that there is an isomorphism of $O_X(X)$-modules $$\Gamma(X,\mathcal{H}om_{O_X}(F,G)) \cong \mathrm{Hom}_{O_X-mod}(O_X,\mathcal{H}om_{O_X}(F,G)).$$

Is there any way to view the right hand side as $\mathrm{Hom}_{O_X-mod}(F,G)$?

Comment: Note that the isomorphism you refer to has nothing to do with $\mathscr{Hom}_{\mathscr{O}_X}(\mathscr{F},\mathscr{G})$: for any $\mathscr{O}_X$-module $\mathscr{H}$, the map

$$\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathscr{O}_X}(\mathscr{O}_X,\mathscr{H})\to\mathscr{H}(X)$$

sending an $\mathscr{O}_X$-module homomorphism $\varphi:\mathscr{O}_X\to\mathscr{H}$ to $\varphi_X(1_{\mathscr{O}_X(X)})$ is an isomorphism of $\mathscr{O}_X(X)$-modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, the module of global sections of the $\mathcal{Hom}(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G})$ is the $\mathcal{O}(X)$-module of morphisms of sheaves $\varphi: \mathcal{F}\rightarrow \mathcal{G}$.